# Creating good-looking software

Tags: user-interface, frameworks, libraries, look-and-feel

I wish to create an application that does not look native, but looks very nice. I want a look similar to indigo studio or garageband, these are just examples of not looking native but looking nice. [This](http://images.apple.com/ilife/garageband/images/carousel-flexgroove-01.jpg) is a nice picture representing Garageband, for those of you who have not seen it. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/442st.png) is a picture of Indigo Studio.
I chose those two applications because they both have a very nice *feel* to them as well as a nice look, they just work. Its a feeling that often comes with native applications.

Now that we have the background over with, we can get to the questions. **What gui libraries or frameworks can produce these kinds of results?** I am open to any language other than C or C++, something with at least a Python binding would be nice, as I have quite a bit of experience in Python. Also, whatever suggestions you make should have bearable to outstanding documentation. I dont want to spend weeks just learning how to use it.
I am not asking, "What is the best?", I am asking, "What are my options and what are the advantages and disadvantages of each?"

**If this sort of result is achieved using images, what are some options, as far as software goes, for creating the images that make up a ui like these?** We all know that Adobe Photoshop and Illustrator can do this sort of thing and more, but lets hear about some software that is free or at least within a reasonable price range for a side-project.

Answer (score 0):

This would be easiest using images, And you can use Gimp, Which is free and has all the features that Photoshop and Illustrator have.

> "GIMP is the GNU Image Manipulation Program. It is a freely
>   distributed piece of software for such tasks as photo retouching,
>   image composition and image authoring."

If you don't want to have to learn how to use gimp a much faster and easier way would be using Microsoft Word or Power-point and set the background image as a Gradient and choose 2 similar colours,
Sorry if this answer is a bit late but if it doesn't help you I hope it helps someone,
Thanks for the submission to the Forums!